# Sum value from a list comparing with other list in Ansible

Tags: ansible

```yaml
virt_server:                       
  - name: server5
    pri_sys: prd1
    sec_sys: cont1
    proc: 0.7

  - name: server6
    pri_sys: prd2
    sec_sys: cont2
    proc: 1.0

  - name: server7
    pri_sys: prd1
    sec_sys: cont1
    proc: 1.0

phys_server:
  - name: PRD1 
  - name: PRD2
  - name: CONT1
  - name: CONT2
  - name: DR
```

I want to sum the value `proc` of the `virt_server` that belong to each `phys_server.` I tried to make a nested loop when `pri_sys` is equal to `phys_server.name`. It have to sum and store in a variable.

I expect the following list:

```yaml
phys_proc:
  - name: PRD1
    proc_total: 1.7
  - name: PRD2
    proc_total: 1.0
```

Comment: `I tried to make a nested loop when prisys is equal to phys_server.name it have to sum and store in a var.` I don't see any trace of that try in your question. Where is the code your wrote for that ? Please edit your question and add it there with the error or result you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a nested loop, as there are Jinja filters to filter lists of dictionaries that can do what you need with a single loop.

Namely, the filter you want to look for is [`selectattr`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.selectattr) that gives you the possibility to filter a list of dictionary based on a [test](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#list-of-builtin-tests).

So, here would be the fact you are looking for:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    phys_proc: >-
      {{ 
        phys_proc | default([]) 
        + [{
          'name': item.name, 
          'proc_total': virt_server
            | selectattr('pri_sys', '==', item.name | lower)
            | sum(attribute="proc") 
            | float
        }]
      }}
  loop: "{{ phys_server }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.name }}"
```

This would give you the full list of all the physical servers. If you only want those that have a total of processor used greater than zero, you can use a `selectattr`, once again:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: phys_proc | selectattr('proc_total', '>', 0)
```

---

Given the playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        phys_proc: >-
          {{ 
            phys_proc | default([]) 
            + [{
              'name': item.name, 
              'proc_total': virt_server
                | selectattr('pri_sys', '==', item.name | lower)
                | sum(attribute="proc") 
                | float
            }]
          }}
      loop: "{{ phys_server }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.name }}"
      vars:
        virt_server:                       
          - name: server5
            pri_sys: prd1
            sec_sys: cont1
            proc: 0.7

          - name: server6
            pri_sys: prd2
            sec_sys: cont2
            proc: 1.0

          - name: server7
            pri_sys: prd1
            sec_sys: cont1
            proc: 1.0

        phys_server:
          - name: PRD1 
          - name: PRD2
          - name: CONT1
          - name: CONT2
          - name: DR
    
    - debug:
        var: phys_proc

    - debug:
        var: phys_proc | selectattr('proc_total', '>', 0)
```

This yields:

```
TASK [set_fact] *******************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=PRD1)
ok: [localhost] => (item=PRD2)
ok: [localhost] => (item=CONT1)
ok: [localhost] => (item=CONT2)
ok: [localhost] => (item=DR)

TASK [debug] **********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  phys_proc:
  - name: PRD1
    proc_total: 1.7
  - name: PRD2
    proc_total: 1.0
  - name: CONT1
    proc_total: 0.0
  - name: CONT2
    proc_total: 0.0
  - name: DR
    proc_total: 0.0

TASK [debug] **********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  phys_proc | selectattr('proc_total', '>', 0):
  - name: PRD1
    proc_total: 1.7
  - name: PRD2
    proc_total: 1.0
```

Comment: thanks, it works! But i dont understand why the second debug doesnt show as yours: TASK [test : debug] *********************************************************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/roles/test/tasks/main.yml:107
ok: [localhost] => {
    "phys_proc | selectattr('proc_total', '>', 0)": "<generator object select_or_reject at 0x7f10eb497b48>"
}

Comment: Because you are on an old version of Ansible. Throw in a `| list` filter and you would be good to go: `phys_proc | selectattr('proc_total', '>', 0) | list`.

Comment: yes thanks, for the respond. A few minutes ago i put list and it works.

Comment: Im trying to add to phys_proc the value of virt_server.sec_sys:  {{ 
            phys_proc | default([]) 
            + [{
              'name': item.name, 
              'proc_total': virt_server
                | selectattr('pri_sys', '==', item.name | lower)
                | sum(attribute="proc") 
                | float,
              'SEC_SYS': virt_server
                | map(attribute='sec_sys')
                |list
            }]
          }}

but is not working correctly